# django migrations in postgresql fails (Even default migrations but works in sqlite and mysql)

Tags: django, postgresql, migrate

I created a new django project and added the following database settings in setings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS':{'options': '-c search_path=resttest'}
    }
}
```

I just ran "python manage.py migrate"

But it this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk" does not exist
```

When is try changing the Database setting with default sqlite or to MySQL it works fine.
I even tried using `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'` as shown in the documentation.
Can someone help me out in guessing what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'your_custom_database_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS':{'options': '-c search_path=resttest'}
    }
}
```

the problem is you are accessing the default database of the postgres database, create another database with a different name and migrate.

Comment: Thanks!. It worked when i changed from default database to custom database

Comment: great to know that, if the answer helped dont forget to accept the ans

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then do following. Install PostgreSQL and its required package.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Log in as a postgres user, as by default only this user has privileges to create a database in PostgreSQL.

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Now, you are logged in as postgres user. Create the database user and assign necessary privileges to it.

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ createuser --interactive -P
Enter name of role to add: db_user
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
postgres@ubuntu:~$
```

In above example, database username is db_user. You can give the name as per your wish. Create database now. Give an appropriate name to database as well, as per your Django application.

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ createdb --owner db_user django_db
```

here db_user is a database user and django_db is a database name. Now logout from postgres user.

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ logout
```

Now, we need to configure PostgreSQL so that it can communicate with Django application. For this, install psycopg2 database adapter. But this adapter has some package dependencies, so first install them.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python3-dev
```

Now install,

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Now, configure database section in your project's settings.py file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': '<password you entered when creating db_user>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Now, migrate the database.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I hope this helps.

Best,

Dhaval